# Troubles using os.system()

Tags: python-3.x

I've created myself a little app that creates an .html document which contains pictures from the same directory as the app. The file creation works as it should but at the end of the program, there is a command to also open the .html document and that's what's acting up.

After the .html is created the console gives me an error message saying 'system can't find stated unit. Error occurred while processing: <.word>'

The new .html file is named after the folder it's in and the name contains spaces. The error message I get repeats for every word in the folder name.

```
import os

dir = os.getcwd().split("""\\""")
Chapter = dir[-1] + ".html"

HTML = open(Chapter,"w")

HTML.write(""" <!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>""" + dir[-1] + """</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #000000
}
</style>""")

PageList = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
PageList.remove("HTML.py")
PageList.remove(Chapter)


for Page in PageList:
    HTML.write(""" <img src=" """ + Page + """ ">  </img> """)

HTML.close()

print("DONE!")

print("file to open - " + Chapter)
os.system(Chapter)
```

The console looks like this:http://prntscr.com/mw0aj5

Comment: What do you think `os.system` does?

Comment: Your filename has spaces in it, which means the entire filename and extension need to be wrapped in double quotes. You can test that yourself by opening a command prompt and manually typing the exact filename your current code is using.

Comment: @ForceBru I know what it does and it worked with one word file names proof:https://youtu.be/rrza1T_REyQ I just don't know how to deal with spaces